# How to check whether a filename exist in drawable folder in android?

Tags: android

I have to check whether the "filename" is exist in drawable folder or not. How can i do that?

```
//Complete URL
String url="http://websitename/image_1.png";
//Getting Filename from URL
String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: Where does the drawable folder comes in picture here? Are you saving them there?

Comment: are you sure this is the complete question, here(in the above code) i cannot see the significance of drawable either.

Comment: Once you actually build and download your application onto a target, these folders no longer exist; they only exist as folders in your project directory until your application is compiled. So keep in mind that if you were to try and check whether a filename exists in the drawable from within the application then it would always return false, or perhaps even some sort of error.

Comment: @Willis: there are ways to check if a drawable exists or not but here its not clear what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I got a result by doing this...

```
 int id = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```